# Oracle Java - How to lock a row so that no other process can read it?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, oracle10g

I have a use case where i read a group of records from the table, perform some action on it and then update the records. I want that no other application/component is able to read the record during this time period. This is because I want to run the same application on multiple hosts for scalability, but don't want a race condition to occur. My application consumes some SQS change events and applies them to the oracle store. Please suggest what mechanism to use. Will SELECT FOR UPDATE work in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Select for update locks the row and reserves it for you to update, but does not stop others from reading it. And I think you may want to reconsider this idea. Imagine all reports or all queries across a table having inconsistent numbers based on how many people happen to be looking at some of the data, regardless of whether they decide to update it or not?

Or, if the other user queries but can't see the row - will they try to insert it and you either wind up hitting a unique key constraint or dealing with duplicated data?

OR, if I query something once and see it, then re-query and it disappears because someone else queried it - how much confidence will I have the app?

What happens when someone goes on vacation but forgets to close the app - leaving a "missing" row for everyone else for a week?

you might want to research Optimistic Locking to deal with race conditions. Yes, it is work to implement, but better than having an application that delivers inconsistent results! Alternately, you work your screens in two modes - display and edit. User clicks "edit" and you re-fetch FOR UPDATE, do the Edit, and either commit the change or abandon the edit. This technique, however, has become less used as it can often leave rows or even whole tables locked up if the transaction is left unresolved which may require DBA intervention to fix.